Unable to Clear 'Manage Recent Places' in Finder on macOS
I've encountered an issue with clearing the 'Manage Recent Places' list in Finder on my Mac. Previously, I was able to clean this list using the following command in the Terminal:
defaults delete .GlobalPreferences NSNavRecentPlaces

However, this method no longer works. Does anyone know if there has been a change in how to handle this in recent macOS updates? Or is there another command or method I can use to clear the 'Manage Recent Places' list?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!


This is the command updated for macOS Sonoma. It may work in some earlier versions, but I don't know which ones.
defaults delete com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService NSNavRecentPlaces


Could you maybe add a little explanation?

It's the OP's shell command, updated for the current version of macOS. I think that's self-evident.

So please add that to your answer. What may be self-evident to you may not be for others (now or in the future). At least put which version of OS it is for - in a few months it may be different, who knows..? FYI, as it stands, your answer is in the low-quality post review queue - that is how I came upon it.

Big thanks to Linc D. for the helpful answer on clearing 'Manage Recent Places' in Finder on macOS. Your input was invaluable!
This code works on AppleScript for anyone who wants to use it
do shell script "defaults delete com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService NSNavRecentPlaces" 